# How does Instagram or Facebook make a page for each user? {instagram.com/USERNAME}

Tags: facebook, url, instagram, url-parameters

How does big websites like *Facebook* or *Instagram* make a page for each user?
or it is a **URL parameter**? how does that work? **Instagram.com/{USERNAME}?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword is "URL Rewrite". How it is done depends on the server technology being used:

- Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
- Nginx: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/